# How to show single post in each page with using next & previous button Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Fetching data from database i want to show or to display one post/data one at a time and adding feature of next and previous button for anther page, I am new to codeigniter, How to do that.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are referring to pagination, according to the documentation 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html

this is what you need to add in your controller

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 20;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

this is what you add in your view

```
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```